# Replace first instance of char in JSON file using shell script

Tags: shell, sed, replace, char, position

Replace only first occurrence of char in JSON file from a known position and keep going till next block.

I have JSON file which needs to be altered.
There are multiple instances of the sections with nested sub-sections. Each one starts with

```
"values": {
    "Firm":[
        "AAA"
    ],
    "Date":[
        "08/19"
    ],
    "Approval Status":[
        "Completed"
    ]
},
other key1: value pair
other key2: value pair
other key3: value pair
```

Number of child varies between "values" sections. I need to append square brackets inside of "values" block.
First square bracket I append easily with sed.
I also can find position of finishing circle bracket.
How do I replace closing `},` with `}],` but only with "values" section?
So the final output for given section should be:

```
"values":[ {
    "Firm":[
        "AAA"
    ],
    "Date":[
        "08/19"
    ],
    "Approval Status":[
        "Completed"
    ]
} ],
other key1: value pair
other key2: value pair
other key3: value pair
```

Pay attention to first `[` and final `],`. These two should be added to each "values": section inside of JSON.

To append first '[' bracket I use this simple sed command which replaces "values:" with "values:[".

```
sed -i -e 's/\"values\":/\"values\":[/g' file.json
```

I can find a position `${pos}` of of two chars at the end of the block `},` where closing square bracket should go, but how do I force either sed or awk to replace only at that position?
What I tried replaces at each line.
I tried:

```
sed -i -e 's/\(.\{195\}\)./\1],/' file.json
```

this command adds `],` to each line (if line has 195 chars in it. If line is  shorter then it being skipped). 195 is a number where closing `},` occurred starting from "values".

Comment: (1) Don't use line oriented tools for parsing JSON, use a syntax-aware one like [tag:jq] (2) See [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and [mcve]

Answer (score -1):

You should use correct tools for JSON file, but if that is not possible, try this:

```
sed -i 's/\("values":\)/\1[/g; s/},/] },/g' file.json
"values":[ {
    "Firm":[
        "AAA"
    ],
    "Date":[
        "08/19"
    ],
    "Approval Status":[
        "Completed"
    ]
] },
other key1: value pair
other key2: value pair
other key3: value pair
```

Comment: Thank you Jotne, What proper JSON tool would you recommend to handle string manipulation?

Comment: @user11997143 I am not a JSON person, but see that other recommends this https://stedolan.github.io/jq/